# Substract two dates delimited by comma in bash

Tags: bash, awk

I have a CSV file like below

```
id,name,age,startdate,enddate,parentid,group
1,Anish,30,20200909140254,20200909140320,15,A
2,Ajo,25,20200909074813,20200909074918,25,B
.
.
.
```

Date is in the format YYYYMMDDHHMMSS. How do I substract field 5 from field 4 and display the output like below using bash (or AWK)?

`Ajo,20200909074813,20200909074918,00000000000105`

Regards,

Anish

Comment: Kindly do add your efforts in form of code in your question and let us know then, its highly encouraged on Stack overflow for all users to add in their questions(Not my down vote btw).

Answer (score 1):

Might work something like

```
awk ' BEGIN {FS = ","}; {print $2 "," $4 "," $5}' FILENAME.csv
```

Comment: More like: `awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS=","}{printf("%s,%s,%s,%014d\n",$2,$4,$5,$5-$4)}' file`